# Unable to perform any operations on a django-app-model deployed on heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, heroku-postgres

Developed an API having one module(task) which works on local server. Since I deployed it on Heroku with same database and records, which i'm able to access through bash, but **unable to perform any of the CRUD operation on database model(Task) through API endpoints**.

(task) refers to app/module directory

(Task) refers to model

**models.py**

```
class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    check = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_to_do = models.DateField(default='2019-05-26', null=True, blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True)
```

**views.py**

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    data = request.body
    valid_json = is_json(data)
    if not valid_json:
        json_data = json.dumps({'msg': 'Invalid JSON data'})
        return HttpResponse(json_data, content_type='application/json', status=400)
    task = json.loads(data)
    form = TaskForm(task)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save(commit=True)
        json_data = json.dumps({'msg': 'Saved Successfully'})
        return HttpResponse(json_data, content_type='application/json', status=200)
    if form.errors:
        json_data = json.dumps(form.errors)
        return HttpResponse(json_data, content_type='application/json', status=400)
```

**Error by Heroku logs**

```
ProgrammingError at /admin/task/task/add/
relation "task_task" does not exist at LINE 1: 

INSERT INTO "task_task" ("title", "check", "date_to_do", "ti...

             ^
```

Comment: Did you run migrations? Did you set your database settings correctly to use Heroku's Postgres add-on?

Comment: Yes I  did makemigrations as well as migrate but I don't know about what to do with add-ons? Please ellaborate a bit and i know my dyno was running as I was able to access Task database table using `bash: ...dumpdata..`

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration#settings-py-changes

Comment: And no, of course it doesn't have anything to do with CSRF. But also you absolutely shouldn't be disabling them.

Comment: Check you have did this . Heroku run python manage.py migrate

Comment: Yes i did. Please read the comments above.